# Access VM's localhost on host

Tags: virtual-machine, port, host, parallels

On my Mac (host), I'm running an web server on parallels VM and I would access to it on my host.
The server is running at http://localhost:44345 and I can't access with the VM's IP (10.211.55.3).
But I can access web server on VM which is running on my host...

What can I do ?

Thanks you.

Comment: How did you configure the Parallels network ? Does the IP work inside the VM ? Provide the output of netstat

Comment: Parallels is on Share Network and I can't access the server by VM's IP...

Comment: If it doesn't listen on the IP inside the VM it also can not listen to outside connections